# Android java code to remove recurring zeros from 3rd place after decimal point

Tags: java, android, regex, decimal

Following is the Java code to check if the number is whole number or decimal number and display the result accordingly:

```
if (result % 1 == 0) {
    String finalResultString = String.format("%.0f", result); 
} else {
    BigDecimal decimalResult = new BigDecimal(result);
    String resultString = String.format("%.15f", decimalResult);
}
```

But in the decimal part:

1) If I run 66%6, I get 3.960000000000000 but I want the answer to be 3.96 only. So I do not want the unnecessary zeros to be displayed.

2) If I run 99 x 65.00055, I want the answer to be 15 digits in after decimal place like 6435.054450000000543

So the thing is - I don't want zeros depending on the leading digit. Like if the result is 5.645345600000000 or 3.960000000000000, I want the result to be either 5.6453456 or 3.96. If the result is 6435.054450000000540, I want 14 digits of precision in the result to be shown since i don't want the last unnecessary zero to be shown. If the result is 6435.000000000000003, I want all the 15 digits of precision to be shown since there are no unnecessary zeros at the end

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: What does the 15 in `"%.15f"` mean?

Comment: @JoeC, I have updated the question. I want the answer to be 15 digits in decimal places, so I can't do "%.2f". but in first case, I don't need unnecessary zeros

Comment: "I want the answer to be 15 digits in decimal places" and "I want the answer to be 3.96 only" do not agree. Either you want 15 places after the radix point, or you want the natural number of places without extra zeros. Which is it?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I want both. Isn't that possible through some if-else condition? Or some regular expression? Just asking if its possible

Comment: "Isn't that possible through some if-else condition?" -- possibly. You would need to come up with the rule for the `if`. You have cited two examples (neither of which appear to be mathematically correct, but that's another matter). There are an infinite number of floating-point numbers, and so we cannot readily determine what your rule is. For example, is your rule "I want 15 places after the radix point for numbers whose leading digit is 6"?

Comment: @CommonsWare, "Is your rule 'I want 15 places after the radix point for numbers whose leading digit is 6?'" - I dint understand whats this

Comment: You want 15 digits of precision for `6435.054450000000543`, but you do not want 15 digits of precision for `3.960000000000000`. What is the rule for when you want 15 digits of precision and when you do not. The leading digit of `6435.054450000000543` is `6`, while the leading digit of `3.960000000000000` is not `6`. Do you want 15 digits of precision when the leading digit of the number is `6`? If not, what is the rule for when you want 15 digits of precision and when you do not? For example, if the rule is "I don't want extra zeros", then IIRC leave off the precision entirely.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I don't want zeros depending on the leading digit. Like if the result is 5.645345600000000 or 3.960000000000000, I want the result to be either 5.6453456 or 3.96. If the result is 6435.054450000000540, I want 14 digits of precision in the result to be shown since i don't want the last unnecessary zero to be shown. If the result is 6435.000000000000003, I want all the 15 digits of precision to be shown since there are no unnecessary zeros at the end

Comment: Then IIRC leave off the precision entirely. Use `%f`, not `%.15f`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, If I use %f, and then run 66%6, I get the result as 3.960000

Comment: `String resultString = (String.format("%.15f", decimalResult)).replaceAll("0+$","");`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the decimal scale to 2:

```
decimalResult = decimalResult.setScale(2);
```